# How to execute a function in React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I m a beginner in React please can someone help in this 
I wrote this function :

```
import React, {
Component }
from 'react';
import './Grid.css';
import test from "../product.json";
import $ from 'jquery';


class Grid extends Component {

makeGrid = () =>{

    var data = test.map( x => [ x.name, x.price, ] );

    $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $('.boxes').append('<div className = "boxi"> Success </div>')

    });
```

I want to execute this function so i tried :

```
render() {


    return (
        <div className = "Grid" >
        < section className = "boxes" >

        < /section> < /div > );

        <h2> {this.makeGrid}</h2>

 }
}

export default Grid;
```

but nothing happen even the console.log does not work .
Please can someone help me .

Answer (score 1):

Two problems i noticed. This is not a react thing. Its a javaScript . `this.makeGrid` calls your function definition , but it doesn't execute it. To execute it, you need the opening and closing brackets. So basically

```
makeGrid = () =>{

}
```

and

```
<h2> {this.makeGrid}</h2>
```

Should render the function string. However.

```
<h2> {this.makeGrid()}</h2>
```

Should execute your function in JavaScript.

The second problem i am suspecting, `makeGrid` is a function in the class. It isn't necessarily recognized  by `this` being the class  itself. So

```
 <h2> {this.makeGrid.bind(this)}</h2>
```

Might be the right way thing to do.

**Update**

Move your method execution to `componentDidMount` lifecyle of react. so add this.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.makeGrid()
}
```

remove `<h2> {this.makeGrid()}</h2>` from render method. Study about `componentDidMount` [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) You don't need to call your method in render like that. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: @MrabetIheb i noticed your function doesn't return anything. What else do you expect to render ?

Comment: I'm expecting to print in console ready and to render `<div className = "boxi"> Success </div>` so it will render Success

Comment: @MrabetIheb then you are doing it wrong in that case. Call it here in https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount . REad about it and pls remove the calling from your render method./ Move your h2 to the function

Comment: The way you're appending stuff is not the React way. Don't use jQuery to directly manipulate the DOM, do it properly in React.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Grid.css';
import test from "../product.json";
import $ from 'jquery';


class Grid extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    this.makeGrid = this.makeGrid.bind(this);
  }
 
  makeGrid = () => {
    var data = test.map( x => [ x.name, x.price, ] );
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $('.boxes').append('<div className = "boxi"> Success </div>')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Grid">
        <section className="boxes">
        </section> 
      < /div >
      <h2>
        {this.makeGrid()}
      </h2>
  );     
 }
}

export default Grid;
```

You need to bind `this` to the makeGrid method.